# what the meaning of "glide through" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't understand the meaning of this verb (glide through) in the sentence:

> As I watched, the small girl rose with her tray and walked away with a quick graceful lope that belonged on a runway. I watched, amazed at her lithe dancer's step, till she dumped her tray and **glided through** the back door, faster than I would have thought possible.

If anybody could help.

Comment: Definition of "glide" in the dictionary:  *to move smoothly and continuously along, as if without effort or resistance, as a flying bird, a boat, or a skater.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Glide* is used metaphorically here, since humans do not glide on land unless they are in a wheeled vehicle (skates included), or in flight. In this case it is used to emphasize the speed and ease through which the girl performed the action, an emphasis on the grace by using a verb which is not usually applied to walking people.